# Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://api.twitter.com:443

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, twitter

I am a trying to get a twitter feed displayed on the home page of my Zend application, so far I have my IndexController code:

```
// ---------------Twitter Feed
        $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
    $token->setParams(array(
        'oauth_token' => 'token',
        'oauth_token_secret' => 'tokSecret',
    ));

    $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
        'username' => 'usrname',
        'accessToken' => $token,
        'oauthOptions' => array(
            'consumerKey' => 'consKey',
            'consumerSecret' => 'consSecret',
        )
    ));

    $options = array('accessToken' => $token);




    $this->view->twitter_timeline = $twitter->statuses->userTimeline();
```

Which is giving me the error:

```
exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://api.twitter.com:443. Error #-223657718: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?'
```

I can connect to the api.twitter.com through my browser so it's not a proxy issue..

Comment: Ah yes, "Unable to find the socket transport 'ssl'" is the key bit here. It means the openssl extension is not enabled. Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed instructions for enabling OpenSSL, this fixed the error!